# Slice text in two without breaking tags in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that I managed to put up by combining different resources. What this does is that it takes html of a content and breaks it into two halves (for a read more application). Following code is such that it doesn't break a word (waits until the end of word).

```
var minCharCount = 600;
var divcontent = $('#myDiv').html();

var firstHalf = divcontent.substr(0, minCharCount);
firstHalf = firstHalf.substr(0, Math.min(firstHalf.length, firstHalf.lastIndexOf(" ")));

var secondHalf = divcontent.substr(firstHalf.length, divcontent.length);
```

However, one last issue with this is that it can break html tags resulting in bad code. Is there a way to make sure that the code breaks them in two after any potential tag ends?

Edit: may be it was a little difficult to understand. What I want is:

```
long text comes here with tags like <b>bold</b> or even <i>italic</i>.
                              ^1         ^2    ^3
```

So my point is if we break at `1` its fine, but if we break at `2` and append the two parts somewhere, we get problems. So before breaking at `2` we need to check if it is in the middle of a tag. If it is then wait until the tag ends and then break: i.e. at `3`.

Answer (score 0):

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j5YYT/)

instead of

```
 $('#myDiv').html();
```

run the function on the string returned from

```
  $('#myDiv').text();
```

This way you don't get any html tags in the input string.

http://api.jquery.com/text/

UPDATE:
(in response to comment)

since you want the html tags, then you can loop through the children() of the target, measure the length of their .text(), and add them to the out put until you reach the minChars amount. Then do the same for the last child you reached, until you reach the closest amount of text to the target char count.

children() excludes text nodes, so you have to use contents().
however, this approach is cumbersome. I think your best bet is to create a range object
see here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.createRange

Comment: This will strip all tags. Not what I want.

Comment: I played around with a function that loops through content nodes. Haven't solved it yet. I am posting the fiddle here in you case you wish to play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/XBE6w/1/.  you can try other approach of using regex to detect if the last character in your string is in html markup.